# jquery selector popping error message in IE when selector is null?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a share javascript file that uses jquery, call it **common.js**, and its used by 2 pages, say **hello.html** and **world.html**.  The script includes event handlers for:

```
$("#helloPageButton").click(function () { ... });
$("#worldPageButton").click(function () { ... });
```

This all works fine in Chrome, Firefox, but in IE hello.html throws that error saying "Object expected" at the line of those selectors.

How do I get IE to **not throw an error and move on** if the selector is not found, ie - is null?

Here's another example: this does not work in IE:

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" id="helloButtonID" value="This is the hello button">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#worldButtonID").click(function(){
     alert("The world button is not on the webapge.");   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JQuery does not return null when a selector does not match any elements; it returns an empty array. Will you post the entire statement?

Comment: jalynn2 I just added some code to the post that shows the problem in IE, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for existence of button before adding click event to button

```
if ($("#helloButtonID").length > 0){
    $("#helloButtonID").click(function(){
         alert("The world button is not on the webapge.");   
    });
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fhvnf/2/)

Comment: This shouldn't be unnecessary. If a jQuery call doesn't select anything, then any calls to it (such as `.click()` here) should have no effect. If it does, then it's a jQuery bug.

Comment: yeah so its a jquery bug but I still need a fix, and RVGs fix worked.